# How do I identify the correct clustering algorithm for the available data?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I have the sample data of **flight routes**, number of searches for that route, gross profit for the route, number of transactions for the route. I want to bucket **flight routes** which shows similar characteristics based on above mentioned variables. What are the steps to fix on the particular clustering algorithm?

Below is sample data which I would like to cluster.

```
Route Clicks Impressions CPC Share of Voice Gross-Profit Number of Transactions Conversions

AAE-ALG 2   25  0.22        $4.00   2   1
AAE-CGK 5   40  0.21        $6.00   1   1
AAE-FCO 1   25  0.25        $13.00  4   1
AAE-IST 8   58  0.30        $18.00  3   2
AAE-MOW 22  100 0.11        $1.00   6   5
AAE-ORN 11  70  0.21        $22.00  3   2
AAE-ORY 8   40  0.18        $3.00   4   4
```

Comment: I'm probably not the person to give a complete answer to this. However, it might be helpful to explain what your end goal is (targeted sales?), which might simplify the analysis. Have you done any regression/correlation analysis to understand which (if any) variables correlate positively or negatively and how strong this correlation is? If there are strongly divergent relationships between pairs all over the place, I imagine the complexity of the clustering procedure will grow very rapidly and business acumen might be needed to determine the important factors, not just maths.

Comment: Clustering algorithms are not magic wands. There won't be any reliable solution where you would just dump your data in and get a meaningful output out.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse glad I was going along the right lines then. You've answered a lot of q's about clustering; for a professional, would it be possible to cluster in this many dimensions and ever get something meaningful? I can't picture it. I've only ever clustered in 2D, and default to regression for anything higher order. I'm just curious, it feels to me like that's what the OP is really looking for.

Comment: Yes. Preprocessing and understanding the data, visualizing the results etc. is key. But often, there are no clusters as you would like to have in your data, too. You need to be able to recognize that situation, too.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I understand there is no reliable solution in clustering but if you can direct me the way in which i can approach on this or something which i can read upon it will be really helpful.

Comment: Find a working visualization. Once you have a good visualization where you can literally *see* clusters, a clustering algorithm may work on that (and you will be able to tell if it worked, by visualizing the clustering). Literally spend days on preprocessing to get a good visualization *first*.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems an N dimension clustering problem where N is the number of features, N = 7 *(Route, Clicks, Impressions, CPC, Share of Voice, Gross-Profit, Number of Transactions, Conversions)*. 
I think if you preprocess the feature values to be able to interpret distance on them you can apply K-means for clustering your data.

E.g. Route can be represented by the distance* of the airports: dA  than you can find diff between 2 distances* that will be the distance between them: d = ABS(dA - dA')

Don't forget to [scale your features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling).